# How can I choose different default apps?

Tags: applications

I would like to use [GLiv](http://guichaz.free.fr/gliv/) (an OpenGL image viewer) as standard action by clicking at pictures.
How do I manage this?

Answer (score 10):

GLiv is an outdated piece of software (last update was back in 2011), which doesn't follow standards of modern Linux desktops. Therefore it lacks proper desktop integration in elementary OS.

Even Guillaume Chazarain, the creator of GLiv, suggest at the [official GLiv homepage](http://guichaz.free.fr/gliv/) to switch to another picture viewer:

> Note that gliv-1.9.7 is probably the last release of GLiv. Other image
>   viewers like Eye of GNOME are now sufficiently fast that I don’t use
>   GLiv anymore. There will be new releases only if I receive bug
>   reports.

I'd suggest you follow his advice and pick another application.

Usually it's very easy to choose another picture viewer.

1. Open *System Settings*
2. Click at *Applications*
3. Choose another installed *Image Viewer*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What about another terminal? I want to use tilix instead of elementary default terminal.